# Enabling AHCI with Sysprep for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, norton-ghost

I am preparing an image (Ghost) at work and our newer "standard desktop" use SSDs. My boss has directed me to make it so the image will enable ahci when we image the newer desktops. So I found the proper drivers and prepared the Syspref.inf. After imaging if I have AHCI enabled in the BIOS it constantly restarts. If I disable it, it installs fine. Yet if I go in and turn on AHCI in the BIOS again, constant restarts. Below is the last part of Syspref.inf

Syspref.inf

```
[Sysprep]
    BuildMassStorageSection = Yes

[SysprepMassStorage]
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4392&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4393&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7802&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7803&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4391&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4392&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4393&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4394&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7801&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7802&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7803&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7804&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\amd\ahcix86.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C1&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C5&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2922&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2929&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3A02&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3A22&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B29&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B2F&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B22&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C02&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C03&CC_0106 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iaahci.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C3&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iastor.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27C6&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iastor.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2822&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iastor.inf
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_282A&CC_0104 = %systemdrive%\Sysprep\drivers\storage\intel\iastor.inf
```

Comment: What steps are you using to run Sysprep?

Comment: I use 'Mini-Setup' and 'Reseal'.

Comment: Is AHCI enabled in the bios during installation? It needs to be.

Comment: If I have ahci enabled during installation it just constantly reboots.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your sysprep.inf is wrong.

When you download the AHCI drivers, you need to basically include all the devices in the driver's inf into the sysprep.inf file.  I've noticed two different lines on my sysprep.inf comapared to yours.

But I haven't updated our image in a while. Best that you double check the inf files.

Comment: I double checked that when I redownloaded the drivers to see if they were the issue.